# setting up UDpipe server in local machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, udpipe

I am trying to set up udpipe server in my local machine (version 2.10).
I have installed the requirements given in their [github](https://github.com/ufal/udpipe/tree/udpipe-2)

below is the error which I encounter when I try to run udpipe2_server.py

```
2023-12-26 11:41:28.060713: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-26 11:41:28.152568: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:41:28.152588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-12-26 11:41:28.174947: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-26 11:41:28.594525: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:41:28.594616: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:41:28.594625: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/udpipe2_server.py", line 26, in <module>
    import udpipe2
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/udpipe2.py", line 19, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 469, in <module>
    _keras._load()
```

I tried installing wembedding_service yet got error

```
2023-12-26 11:45:15.604154: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-26 11:45:15.695350: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:45:15.695370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-12-26 11:45:15.717002: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-26 11:45:16.149980: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:45:16.150044: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-12-26 11:45:16.150053: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/wembedding_service/./start_wembeddings_server.py", line 58, in <module>
    server = wembeddings_server.WEmbeddingsServer(args.port, args.dtype, wembeddings_lambda)
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/wembedding_service/wembeddings/wembeddings_server.py", line 102, in __init__
    self._wembeddings = wembeddings_lambda()
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/wembedding_service/./start_wembeddings_server.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    wembeddings_lambda = lambda: wembeddings.WEmbeddings(threads=args.threads, preload_models=args.preload_models)
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/wembedding_service/wembeddings/wembeddings.py", line 77, in __init__
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 469, in <module>
    _keras._load()
  File "/home/sumanth/sumanth.k/udpipe/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 41, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
```

Can anyone guide me with installation of udpipe in my local machine?